# How do we add swift compile flag to `gym` when using fastlane

Tags: fastlane

There are not much documentation about this here in the office documentation page https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/.

The only thing that mentioned compile flag is:

> **xcargs**:
>   Pass additional arguments to xcodebuild for the build phase. Be sure to quote the setting names and values e.g. OTHER_LDFLAGS="-ObjC -lstdc++"

This is what we have currently:

```
gym(options.merge(:export_xcargs => "-allowProvisioningUpdates", 
                  :export_method => "development"))
```

We would like now adding this flag to our build:

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100
```

We don't want to add it to Xcode project file like this https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times since we only want this check on the build machine which uses fastlane.

So this is what we tried:

```
gym(options.merge(:export_xcargs => "-allowProvisioningUpdates", 
                  :export_method => "development",
                  :xcargs => "-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100"))
```

But it keeps complaining about this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-Xfrontend'
```

How do we add this flag properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works!

```
gym(options.merge(:export_xcargs => "-allowProvisioningUpdates", 
                  :export_method => "development",
                  :xcargs => "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS='-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100'"))
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, this was one of the only solutions I found on how to send xcargs through to xcode with an env variable. Works for GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS in the same way too

Answer (score 0):

Since it's gym, use `export_xcargs:` instead of `xcargs:`  and see related answer here if you need to assign a value for the flag  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57972046/4970749