# Passing environment variables from fastlane to Xcode build phase script

Tags: xcode, git, tfs, xcodebuild, fastlane

Is it possible (and if so, how) to pass an environment variable from the script that runs fastlane down to an Xcode Run Script Phase?

My end goal is to read the current git branch name in the Run Script Phase. Our CI is ran by Team Foundation Server which does a `git checkout` of explicit commits, not branches, so the current branch always shows as `HEAD`.

```
TFS -> fastlane -> gym -> xcodebuild -> script that needs the branch
```

It is possible to get the branch that triggered the build only via an environment variable set by TFS. My plan is to get that value down to the Xcode script to do what I need.

I would prefer not to use this as it passes all enviornment variables to the build process, if I understand it correctly.

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment -bool NO
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To pass env-variables to BuildPhases use `xcargs` in `Fastfile`:

```
build_app(workspace: ..., scheme: ..., xcargs: "SOMEVAR1='one' SOMEVAR2='two'")
```

This command generates `xcodebuild ... SOMEVAR1='one' SOMEVAR2='two'`, and then these variables will become available in Build Phases.

Comment: The syntax is quoted, so something like this: "BUILD_NUMBER='43' VERSION_NUMBER='12'"

Comment: Does boolean values has to be quoted as well? For example when you have: "-allowProvisioningUpdates -UseModernBuildSystem=NO"

Comment: How to i use these inside the build phases scripts?

Comment: @MrSpring like env vars: `$SOMEVAR1`